# How can I match start of the line or a character in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

For example, this is ok:

```
my $str = 'I am $name. \$escape';
$str =~ s/[^\\]\K\$([a-z]+)/Bob/g;
print $str; # 'I am Bob. \$escape';
```

But below is not what I was expected.

```
my $str = '$name';
$str =~ s/[^\\]\K\$([a-z]+)/Bob/g;
print $str; # '$name';
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: What if your string is `\\$name`?

Comment: Change the regex to `(?:^|[^\\])\K\$([a-z]+)`

Comment: @shawnhcorey: No, there must be either start of string or ``\`` char before `$`. You suggest start of string and any char *other than* ``\`` before `$`. The original issue is that a character class is used instead of a grouping construct, and that issue is addressed in my answer below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: you should read the question one more time (in particular the first example that is "ok"). I think the word "character" in the title doesn't stand for a backslash, but for a character that isn't a backslash.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Even if that is so amd the title is not aligned with what OP tried, it makes no difference: the point is to use a grouping construct. Or alternation inside a positive lookbehind, but since `\K` is used, it is all the same. But to account for those who understand the question that way, I added an update to my (already accepted) answer below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, the first example by the OP has `$name` replaced but `\$escape` **not replaced**, which is what my regex does. What is not clear if the OP only allows backslashes before a dollar sign. If he wants backslashes before other characters, the regex has to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I match *start of the line or a character* in Perl?

The circumflex inside a character class loses the meaning of the start-of-string anchor. Instead of a character class, you need to use a non-capturing group:

```
$str =~ s/(?:^|\\)\K\$([a-z]+)/Bob/g;
          ^^^^^^^^
```

This `(?:^|\\)` will either assert the position at the string start or will match `\`.

For those who understand the question as *match only if the `$` symbol is not escaped*, the solution will be

```
$str =~ s/(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\K\$([a-z]+)/Bob/g;
```

Here, the `(?<!\\)` zero-width assertion is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if `$` is preceded with `\` symbol and `(?:\\\\)*` will consume any escaped backslashes (if present) before `$` while `\K` match reset operator will discard all these backslashes from the match value.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to match `$` that are not escaped by a backslash, you can change your pattern to:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K\$([a-z]+)
```

This way you don't have to use an alternation since the negative lookbehind matches a position not preceded by a backslash (that includes the start of the string).

In addition, `(?:\\{2})*` prevents to miss cases when a backslash before a `$` is itself escaped with an other backslash. For example: `\\$name`